# how can i enable swipe action on react native?

Tags: react-native

Please can someone help me on how to make my react native app detect when a user swipes left or right? I already researched randomly but seem not to have a positive answer.

So any function or package that can help?

I am mapping through a list of objects and I want the user to view next object in array whenever he swipes ( just like on click ).

It works with onClick but I need it with swipes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do, you can create a carousel using a horizontal Flatlist and use pagination to swipe elements. Please add more details

Comment: Basically, the scenario is like next and prev btn

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try PanResponder from the docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder)

Comment: ok thanks, let me check it out